# How to continue in ajaxified page after response already ended elsewhere

Tags: c#, ajax, telerik, response

Okay, I'll do my best to explain:

I'm using a telerik RadTreeView

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="rtvDistributedReports" runat="server" Skin="Sunset" 
Width="100%" OnClientNodeClicking="ClientNodeClicking" 
OnNodeClick="OnClickOpenReport" EnableViewState="true" />
```

When a child node is clicked I call the OnClickOpenReport function to open a pdf. Here is that function:

```
protected void OnClickOpenReport(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    string navigateUrl = GetNavigateUrl(int.Parse(e.Node.Attributes["FileID"]));
    Response.Redirect(navigateUrl);

    *some other formatting code and a save function*
}
```

I have a little spinning icon showing the page is working. It never stops because the code never gets past the Response.Redirect line. The page that opens the pdf ends the response. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void OnClickOpenReport(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    var script = "StopIconFunction();location.href='" + navigateUrl "';";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "OpenFile", script, true);
}
```

Where `StopIconFunction()` is a javascript function to stop the spinning icon.

Comment: this works fine in chrome, but page formatting gets messed up in IE8. the treeview symbols and some other styling disappear on the page. thanks a lot though.